# Are HTML5 custom elements allowed in <HEAD>

Tags: html, custom-element

I am trying to write some HTML5 standards compliant code, where certain scripts need to be run only after the user has consented to cookies.

The html code looks like this, where the consent-script element, works exactly the same as the script element, however holds off loading the script until the consent has been given.

```
<head>

<consent-script src="myscript.js"></consent-script>

</head>
```

Everything works fine in all browsers,
However when I attempt to validate this using https://validator.w3.org/ , the custom-element tag apparently closes the head section, and generates a pile of errors.

Looking at the specifications, I can't see any reason why custom-elements cant be used in the  section.  But I am not sure.

My question is, can HTML5 custom-elements be used in HEAD?  If I can, then its a bug in the validator service.  If not, then I will have to find another way of not running a script until the right moment.

Thanks.

EDIT. Further investigation (Thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman) leads me to believe that even a browser is moving the custom element out of the head section, into the body section.

Some mock up code:

The source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <my-custom-elem></my-custom-elem>
  <!-- other tags in the HEAD -->
</head>
<body>this is the body
</body>
</html>
```

Yet, chrome developer tools gives me:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <my-custom-elem></my-custom-elem>
  <!-- other tags in the HEAD -->

  this is the body

</body></html>
```

Comment: And if you check F12 , where is your Custom Element? HEAD or BODY?

Comment: The element is in Head, when looked at in a browser...

Edit: Sorry, no its not. Its in <body>

Comment: I am interested to know what ``console.log(document.querySelector("consent-script").parentNode)`` outputs.. becuase in your post you say the element *closes the HEAD section* FYI, I use Custom Elements in the HEAD a lot.

Comment: I haven't experienced any issues yet (other than a validator complaining) I use a CE to generate all script and meta tags in the HEAD See page: https://hexedland.com/ludo.html , if you look at the page-source everything **after** the CE is moved to the body - by the browser-, because as you said, a CE closes the HEAD..Ssince those are ``templates`` , ``style`` and ``script`` tags I don't really care if they are in the HEAD or BODY.. (but they are now BODY children elements! and take up space in CSS grids for example IF the grid is on the BODY)

Comment: Yes, that is what I do with my ``<hexed-head>`` element. its declared with a rendering blocking load ASAP; then creates the whole HEAD... and.. removes itself. So its visible in the page-source, but no longer in de F12 Elements panel. I haven't heard any issues in the past months; only the Validator complains. That is because all Browsers close the HEAD section (as you noticed) and dump everything after in the BODY. But I can't answer your question if all this is *valid*. Since it works for me I haven't asked a question yet at the source: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - I updated the main question, to reflect what I found, inspired by what you asked.

Comment: Make it an issue on https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues, that is where all Browser vendor developers are. They don't read StackOverflow. (well.. maybe they read to keep a finger on what mortals are doing with components; but they don't answer)

Comment: Thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman , I will do.

Comment: Added an extra line in your code to show everything **after** the CE in the HEAD is also now in the BODY

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yeh, thanks.  The same problem happens in Firefox/Safari, not just chrome.  Think I'll find another way

Comment: It is not a problem (IMHO) It is behaviour you have to be aware of. Post the question on the WC issue list. I could be very wrong.